# Copying parts of the bar code and write to the file txt

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript:

```
Dim Stuff, myFSO, WriteStuff, dateStamp

Stuff = "Whatever you want written"

Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WriteStuff = myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Label_1\yourtextfile.txt", 8, True)
WriteStuff.WriteLine(var1)
WriteStuff.Close
SET WriteStuff = NOTHING
SET myFSO = NOTHING
```

which is placed in action in the key.
In the variable "var1" is read barcode reader, bar code EAN13 and after pressing a key to a text file "C:\Label_1\yourtextfile.txt"
is written to a new line with a value of "var1", ie. the bar code

```
2914750018247
```

Then again, when we will scan the bar code

```
2914750007463
```

and press the button
also will be saved in a text file.

Recording will look like this:

```
2914750018247
2914750007463
```

Of course, the scanned file "C:\Label_1\yourtextfile.txt" will be more, eg. 70 different codes but always EAN13.

How you can using VBScript copy or distribute 5 characters namely:

```
01824
00746
...
```

with previously stored all values (5 characters each) in the file "C:\Label_1\ yourtextfile.txt" and yet they all add up and save a new file txt when codes (with five characters each) will be just 70 in line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below example, it processes the lines of source file and cut each line to substring:

```
sSrc = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\barcode.txt"
sDst = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\barcode_part.txt"

' Read content of the source file
sCont = ReadTextFile(sSrc, 0) ' ASCII
' Split source file string into array of lines
aLines = Split(sCont, vbCrLf)
' Loop through each of the lines in array
For i = 0 To UBound(aLines)
    ' Change the value of the element to cut substring
    aLines(i) = Mid(aLines(i), 8, 5)
Next
' Join processed array into resulting string with line breaks
sCont = Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
' Write content to the destination file
WriteTextFile sCont, sDst, 0 ' ASCII

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sContent, sPath, lFormat)
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, lFormat)
        .Write sContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello omegastripes.
Detailed Description of the content and can be considered again?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help